# How to add a custom folder to a Sql Server Management Studio 2008 solution?

Tags: projects-and-solutions, ssms, sql-server-2008

I would like to add custom folders to a Sql Server Management Studio 2008 solution.
Currently only three folders are included: Connections, Queries, and Miscellaneous with no easy way to add or customize this folder layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I recall, you cannot do this, unfortunately. At least not with any "normal" documented methods....

I once even tried to manually edit the resulting `*.ssmssqlproj` file (it's basically a XML-based Visual Studio solution file, after all), but if I recall correctly, even those folders added manually into the proj file were "killed" at next startup and removed.

The whole solution stuff in SSMS is really majorly lacking right now - which is a bit funny since it's really based on the Visual Studio code base, which can handle lots of scenarios in its solutions......

Answer (score 1):

I confirm, that it is not possible in SSMS2005-2008R2. Code simply ignores additional folders.

Answer (score 0):

there was once a free addon @ http://www.sqltreeo.com/
but now they charge for an "nearly" opensource project

the last free edition was 0.3.3 (if you would like to search in the archives)